# OpenCV MSER detect text area - java

Tags: java, opencv

I have a grayscale image. I want to get the text area as a binary image using the MSER opencv in java. I have the code as below

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(image, image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
MSER mser = MSER.create();
List<MatOfPoint> msers = new ArrayList<>();
MatOfRect bboxes = new MatOfRect();
mser.detectRegions(image, msers, bboxes);
```

[I have image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neWte.jpg)

[I want results like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hpit.jpg)